# Для чего используется static в операторе ::?

Tags: php

Для чего используется static в операторе **::** ?

```
return static::Find($id);
```

Comment: Есть вариант, это досутп к переменной класса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ключевое слово static используется для позднего статического связывания, т.е. в классах унаследованных от этого можно будет определить свой статический метод Find() и будет вызываться именно он, а не метод текущего класса. Если вы вместо static укажите self, то будет вызван статический метод Find() текущего класса, даже если в унаследованных классах вы определите собственные статические методы Find().

Так как статические методы принадлежат не объектам, а классам - приходится разруливать ситуацию с их переопределением при помощи отдельных ключевых слов.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Четко, по делу, профессионально.

Answer (score 2):

С помощью '::' мы обращаемся к статическим методам класса. Фишка в том, что, обращаясь к статической функции, мы не инициализируем объект класса.

Comment: Большое спасибо, все слаженно и точно.

Comment: вопрос не про `::`, в про `static::`